# mapper overwriting resolved object

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

i have a mapper which uses resolve factory to turn a dto (with its id populated) to a domain entity.  It all seems to work but in the generated mapper impl, it overwrites the resolved properties from whats in the dto.

mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "springlazy", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, uses = { TicketAccountResolver.class })
public interface TicketAccountMapper {
    /**
     * Converts TicketAccount domain class to DTO
     *
     * @param TicketAccountDto domain class
     * @return TicketAccount DTO class. If null provided, would return null as well.
     */
    TicketAccountDto map(TicketAccount domain);

    /**
     * Converts TicketAccount dto class to domain
     *
     * @param TicketAccountDto domain class
     * @return TicketAccount DTO class. If null provided, would return null as well.
     */
    TicketAccount map(TicketAccountDto dto);
}
```

resolver:

```
@Component
public class TicketAccountResolver {
    @Autowired
    TicketAccountRepository repository;

    @ObjectFactory
    public TicketAccount resolve(TicketAccountDto dto, @TargetType Class<TicketAccount> type) {
        if (null != dto && dto.getId() != null) {
            return repository.findById(dto.getId()).get();
        }
        // TODO not sure on best approach here, throw exception, return null, or do the below
        return new TicketAccount(dto.getId());
    }
```

generated mapper impl:

```
 @Override
    public TicketAccount map(TicketAccountDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        TicketAccount ticketAccount = ticketAccountResolver.resolve( dto, TicketAccount.class );

        ticketAccount.setDisplayName( dto.getDisplayName() );
        ticketAccount.setId( dto.getId() );
        ticketAccount.setName( dto.getName() );

        return ticketAccount;
    }
```

I need it to return the ticketAccount after resolve is called, not overwrite its fields with dto values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `@ObjectFactory` is used to create the object. After that mapstruct will attempt to fill it with mapping actions.

## Disable automapping option

You can add the following `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)` to the mapping method to disable automapping for that mapping method. Only explicitly defined mappings will now be used.

## BeforeMapping option

If you use `@BeforeMapping` you can have it return the value that you want it to have instead. In case it is not found you can return null, in that case mapstruct will create a new ticketAccount based on the dto.

```java
    @BeforeMapping
    public TicketAccount resolve(TicketAccountDto dto, @TargetType Class<TicketAccount> type) {
        if (null != dto && dto.getId() != null) {
            return repository.findById(dto.getId()).get();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

would result in something like:

```
 @Override
    public TicketAccount map(TicketAccountDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        TicketAccount ticketAccount = ticketAccountResolver.resolve( dto, TicketAccount.class );

        if (ticketAccount != null) { return ticketAccount; }
// no TicketAccount found, mapstruct will now attempt to initialise it.
        ticketAccount = new TicketAccount(); // if empty constructor exists, otherwise it will initialise the constructor fields first with dto values before calling it with the correct arguments.
        ticketAccount.setDisplayName( dto.getDisplayName() );
        ticketAccount.setId( dto.getId() );
        ticketAccount.setName( dto.getName() );

        return ticketAccount;
    }
```